# Google Sheets - Highlight cell based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database with hundreds (will be thousands) of entries related to utility assets.  These assets are ranked and inspected on various conditions.  There are multiple inspections done periodically and the old inspection data is accessible along side the new data.  I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight a cell in column Q, based on duplicate rows in column G.  For example: I have one asset with an ID of 1234 in column G with 3 different inspections, and thus three entries on different rows.  I want to highlight column Q if that value (in column Q) is not the same among all three inspections in the various rows.  Is this something that is possible?  I have tried various combinations using the =IF, =COUNTIF(S) functions.  The end goal here is to recognize that column Q is not equal on all three inspections so that it can be updated to be the same value.

In the example sheet the value in column Q on row 3 does not match row's 4, 5.  The value in column Q on row 7 does not match row's 6, 8, and 9.  The information in all Column besides G is subject to change, so it must be based off that value.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xAvRaxMii3Xijbuw3ITKo0CBPhXkW9-Bgdg_LRxv1qA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could there be more than one incorrect value for a particular ID? If you had two values, one correct and one incorrect, how would you know which was the incorrect one? Or am I over-thinking this - maybe you just want to highlight all the ones where the values aren't all the same?

Comment: I'm not concerned with whether the value is correct or incorrect.  The value is a rating based on multiple factors, used to prioritize budgets.  It is ambiguous, but must be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, if there are at least as many cells with the same ID but different Q value as there are with the same ID and the same Q value, then the current cell should be highlighted:

```
=countifs(G:G,G3,Q:Q,"<>"&Q3)>=countifs(G:G,G3,Q:Q,Q3)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this formula, but it highlighted multiple entries across the spreadsheet, I believe it needs to search for 'exact' duplication in the cell. i.e. a cell in column G with a value of 15, and also 3156 is causing the cell in column Q to be highlighted.  I'm just not sure where/what to add to the formula to search for exact values.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest - is it possible to show cases in your test data which shouldn't be highlighted?